# How to get count from rows in Linq faster

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I have a linq to get all row count group by Id.
Because of my table is very big it needs very long in Linq (because I have to get the data completly since EF Core 3.0).

```
            var reportCountData = this.context.ReportData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ReportId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

How to make this faster (e.g. without getting all data first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be translated:

```
var reportCountData = from p in this.context.ReportData
            group p by p.ReportId into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            };
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby

Comment: Why this and not mine?

Comment: .GroupBy(..) returns a result of type IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. EF cannot translate a db structure for this. In my proposal the translation is done later by select new with two scalar values as result

Comment: "Why this and not mine?" `AsEnumerable()` runs the query, fetching all the results to the client, and the GroupBy happens there.

Comment: Oh, I didnt knew group by is basicly a to List here... thank you!